# Comparing passwords not working Java

Tags: java

Alright, I'm trying to compare two passwords and output a message if they're correct or if it's a wrong password but there's a problem when it's compiled.

```
    public void setPassword (int passwordSet) {
        passwordSet = password;
    }

    public void checkPassword (int passwordGuess) {
        if (password == passwordGuess) {
            System.out.println("Correct password.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong password.");
        }
    }

    class TestStuffTestDrive {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        TestStuff one = new TestStuff();
        one.setPassword(7558);
        one.checkPassword(7363);
        one.checkPassword(7558);
    }
}
```

And then when I run it this comes out:

> run:
>   Wrong password.
>   Wrong password.

Comment: Storing passwords as int's is really bad practice

Comment: Does this snippet really compile ? I mean, with methods outside of your class declaration !! ??

Comment: @YReg - I didn't copy all of the code. Of course it's declared.

Comment: @atamanroman - As you can see I'm not comparing strings but integers, but I'll keep that in mind anyway.

Comment: You're right - my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to write your `setPassword` method like this:

```
  public void setPassword(int passwordSet) {
      this.password = passwordSet ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your setter method `setPassword()`, change

```
passwordSet = password;
```

to

```
password = passwordSet;
```